# How to handle the popup window in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Use this url--**http://www.indiangiftsportal.com/product_info.php?products_id=kaju-kalash-shivaaz**,

then click `add To cart`, it will show you one popup window in that am not getting how to click that "[image]**"skip"** button.

Any ideas?

Comment: Prasahnth, could you give us a bit more information? What's the code you're using to access the page? The code you've tried that isn't working? The page HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: am using HTML but when am click,  right click of the mouse button it ll not showing option like view Xpth,inspect element with firebug "only for this above popup image page" thanks for giving ur valuable time

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is not being able to click on the element because it's not visible you can use this method:

```
  public static void scrollToElement(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}

WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".close"));
this.scrollToElement(el,driver);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution-

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.indiangiftsportal.com/product_info.php?products_id=kaju-kalash-shivaaz"); 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#clickme input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.close")).click();
```

Hope this helps !